# Scala Play Framework IOException error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, ioexception

I got a project from friend. On windows 7 everything is working ok but when i switch to windows XP i am getting "IOException: Device not ready" error.

Some details:
Windows XP
NTFS file system

Error stack available by Play:

```
Unexpected exception
IOException: Device not ready 
No source available, here is the exception stack trace: 
->java.io.IOException: Urządzenie nie jest gotowe
     java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
     java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
     java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$externalBinaryModified$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Incremental.scala:225)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$externalBinaryModified$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Incremental.scala:222)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$externalBinaryModified$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Incremental.scala:222)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$externalBinaryModified$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Incremental.scala:221)
     scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:146)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$externalBinaryModified$1.apply(Incremental.scala:221)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$externalBinaryModified$1.apply(Incremental.scala:217)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:252)
     scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultKeySet$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(MapLike.scala:171)
     scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultKeySet$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(MapLike.scala:171)
     scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:178)
     scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:347)
     scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultKeySet.foreach(MapLike.scala:171)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:251)
     scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultKeySet.filter(MapLike.scala:165)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$.changedInitial(Incremental.scala:99)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:21)
     sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:20)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:96)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:44)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:31)
     sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:79)
     sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:572)
     sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:572)
     sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf2$1.apply(Structure.scala:578)
     sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf2$1.apply(Structure.scala:578)
     scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
     sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
     sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
     sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
     sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
     sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
     sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
     sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
     sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help? I have already set read / write rigts to all files and folders in the project.

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand: people are supposed to debug your code without seeing it or having any idea of what you are trying to do right? No code, no framework version, just the stacktrace.

Comment: So you are expecting me to include all 50 mb code here? I wrote that i got the code from my friend and it is not working in my case. I'm sure it is not creating any files by itself but probably chaching mechanisms?
Anyway: i thought that community of StackOverflow is going to help and i see here are only haters and blamers. Great job "guys".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. For me, the solution was to run `play clean` and recompile the project.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about your codebase but something about SBT not being able to read your filesystem, could be something with missing permissions, directories deleted from under sbt. Make sure you have read and write permissions to the filesystem where you have your project and that its not out of free space etc.

Answer (score 1):

SBT (the build tool used by Play) is trying to compile your file, but it can't access the filesystem, e.g. if the code is on an external hard drive that has been unmounted.